# I want an array of values of a key from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key-value-coding

I have an array structure like below

```
array
{
     [0]=>
     {
            [name] = "maulik";
            [roleId] = 34;
     }
     [1]=>
     {
            [name] = "ketan";
            [roleId] = 12;
     }
     [2]=>
     {
            [name] = "nitish";
            [roleId] = 40;
     }
     [3]=>
     {
            [name] = "hiren";
            [roleId] = 24;
     }
}
```

I want array of all roleId field by a single php function. Is there any php function available or I have to use like below?

```
$roleIds = array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $roleIds[] = $user['roleId'];
}
```

**Solution for the visitors from search engine....**

```
function getRoleIdsAsArray($index)
{
        return $index['roleId'];
}

$roleIds = array_map("getRoleIdsAsArray" , $users);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `array_map()` is slower than "inline code", probably because of the need to call function for each element. Usually this would not be a bottleneck of a system, though.

Comment: Another option would be to use [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/array_walk), as it allows to pass arbitrary arguments to callback function, so you could call it as `array_map($data, 'callback', 'roleId');` without hardcoding `'roleId'` in callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this one is a solution suitable to you:

```
$roleIds = array_map(function($c) {return $c['roleId'];}, $users);
```

It use [array_map](http://it.php.net/array_map), available since php 4 and [anonymous functions](http://it.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) introduced into php since version 5.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like that. You can turn that into your own function, though I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.